vue Router Console related


package.json
{
  "name": "vue_web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "3.0.6",
    "@mdi/font": "7.4.47",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "3.2.13",
    "axios": "1.6.8",
    "crypto-js": "4.2.0",
    "jquery": "3.7.1",
    "process": "0.11.10",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.2",
    "sweetalert": "2.1.2",
    "vue": "3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "4.3.2",
    "vuetify": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "7.21.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.8.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}





/router/index.js
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from "vue-router";
import Login from "../Pages/Erp/MuzinLogin.vue";
import Memo from "../Pages/Erp/Memo/ObtainMemo.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "app",
    redirect: { name: "mainPage" },
  },
  {
    path: "/main",
    name: "mainPage",
    component: () => import("../Pages/MainPage.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/erp/testLogin",
    name: "muzinLogin",
    component: Login,
  },
  {
    path: "/erp/memo/obtainMemo",
    name: "obtainMemo",
    component: Memo,
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

export default router;





main.js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import router from "./router";
import App from "./App.vue";
import jquery from "jquery";
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import axios from "axios";
import Config from "./plugins/user.js";
const app = createApp(App);
window.$ = jquery;
window.jQuery = jquery;

// 전역 속성으로 axios 설정

app.config.globalProperties.$http = axios;
app.config.globalProperties.$Config = Config;

// 라우터 사용
app.use(vuetify);
app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");
router.isReady().then(() => {
  console.log("Initial route name:", router.currentRoute.value.name);
});





ThisSidebar.vue
<template>
    <v-app>
     <v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        :rail="rail"
        permanent
        @click="rail = false"
      >
        <v-list-item
          title="John Leider"
          nav
        >
          <template v-slot:append>
            <v-btn
              icon="mdi-chevron-left"
              variant="text"
              @click.stop="rail = !rail"
            ></v-btn>
          </template>
        </v-list-item>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-list density="compact" nav>
          <v-list-item
    v-for="item in filteredMenuItems"
    :key="item.title"
    :to="item.route"
    :title="item.title"
    :prepend-icon="item.icon">
</v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            rail: true,
            drawer: true,
            menuItems: [
                { title: 'Dashboard', icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard', route: '/erp/memo/obtainMemo', permission: 'admin' },
                { title: 'Profile', icon: 'mdi-account', route: '/erp/memo/obtainMemo', permission: 'public' },
                // 추가 메뉴 아이템
            ],
            auth: 'admin', // 예시 사용자 권한
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.auth = sessionStorage.getItem('auth') || 'public';
    },
    computed: {
      filteredMenuItems() {
          console.log(this.menuItems.filter(item => item.permission === this.auth)); // 콘솔에 출력하여 데이터 확인
          return this.menuItems.filter(item => item.permission === this.auth);
      },
  },
    methods: {
        // goTo(route) {
        //     this.$router.push(route);
        // },
    },
};
</script>





ObtainMemo.vue
<template>
    <this-sidebar></this-sidebar>
  <div>
    <div>sss</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import swal from 'sweetalert';
import ThisSidebar from '../../../components/ThisSidebar.vue'
export default {
  name: 'ObtainMemo',
  components: {
    ThisSidebar,
  },
  data: () => ({
    userId: '',
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.userId = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
  },
  methods:{
  },
  watch: {
        userId(){
            if (!this.userId) {
                // this.movePage('Main');
            }
        },
    }
}
</script>



I'm sorry.. It's my first time writing it, but I keep getting errors when I type in the source.. Please understand that I upload it as a picture.
I haven't done anything else since I ran the project and ran Page Chrome. But I keep getting warnings in pictures.
I've been asking questions in gpt 4.0 version for 3 days, but I can't fix it even if I fix it with the modifications I received.. I asked the site to ask for help..

can i see your BASE_URL env

Is this a new project ? Because i just create new vuetify project in my local using your code and it compile without any warning

Please read official documentation rather than speaking to an LLM.

Think your issue is basically the vuetify import being wrong, the paths for the router definition so long as right shouldn't cause those warnings in the console but also warnings from missed router paths shouldn't really cause the app to "not load" too.  Also best to start with simplest possible case and only add code as things are still working and be sure to rebuild and fully stop/restart the service with npm if you make changes to the main.js or router.js or other "top level files" not watched by the CLI.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-dbrzvu?file=src%2Fmain.js
Primary things there I think were:
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
import 'vuetify/styles';
import * as components from 'vuetify/components';
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives';

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
});
app.use(vuetify);


See https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#existing-projects
With regard to ChatGPT it can be good at some coding tasks but is particularly bad at managing what versions of various libs are actually compatible with each other so you'll need to check those things in the lib docs and make sure to tell ChatGPT to stick to verisons you know are tested to work together and are in the training data (basically anything a year back or more it should already "know" about).

Thank you.
After package.json comparison, the vue version was changed to remove node_modules, package-lock.json, and the npm install warning was removed.
